# Select field value not returned after saving changes

Tags: plugin-development, select

I've been searching around for an answer to this one but have had no luck thus far… forgive me if it has been answered somewhere before!

I'm currently writing a plugin and I'm using the WordPress Plugin Boilerplate for the first time. I am also, believe it or not, utilising a select field in the admin settings page of said plugin for the first time as well.

The problem that I am running into is that when I save my changes, while all my input fields return their saved values, the select field does not.

Here is where I am creating the select field function to be reused across the plugin:

```
/**
 * Creates a select field.
 *
 * @since       1.0.0
 */
public function field_select( $args ) {

    $defaults['aria']           = '';
    $defaults['blank']          = '';
    $defaults['class']          = '';
    $defaults['context']        = '';
    $defaults['id']             = '';
    $defaults['description']    = '';
    $defaults['label']          = '';
    $defaults['name']           = $this->plugin_name . '-options[' . $args['id'] . ']';
    $defaults['selections']     = array();
    $defaults['value']          = '';

    apply_filters( $this->plugin_name . '-field-select-options-defaults', $defaults );

    $atts = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    if ( ! empty( $this->options[$atts['id']] ) ) {

        $atts['value'] = $this->options[$atts['id']];

    }

    if ( empty( $atts['aria'] ) && ! empty( $atts['description'] ) ) {

        $atts['aria'] = $atts['description'];

    } elseif ( empty( $atts['aria'] ) && ! empty( $atts['label'] ) ) {

        $atts['aria'] = $atts['label'];

    }

    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'partials/' . $this->plugin_name . '-admin-field-select.php' );

}
```

And here is where I am adding a settings field, using `add_settings_field`:

```
add_settings_field(
        'background',
        'Background Colour',
        array( $this, 'field_select_text' ),
        $this->plugin_name . '-customise',
        $this->plugin_name . '-customise',
        array(
            'name'              => 'background',
            'id'                => 'background',
            'selections'        => array(
                0 => array(
                    'label' => 'Brand',
                    'value' => 'brand'
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'label' => 'Transparent',
                    'value' => 'transparent'
                ),
                2 => array(
                    'label' => 'Custom',
                    'value' => 'custom'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

And finally, here is the markup for the select field:

```
<select aria-label="<?php esc_attr( $atts['aria'] ); ?>"
    class="<?php echo esc_attr( $atts['class'] ); ?>"
    id="<?php echo esc_attr( $atts['id'] ); ?>"
    name="<?php echo esc_attr( $atts['name'] ); ?>">

<?php
if ( ! empty( $atts['blank'] ) ) {
    ?>

    <option value><?php esc_html_e( $atts['blank'], $this->plugin_name ); ?></option>

    <?php
}

foreach ( $atts['selections'] as $selection ) {

    if ( is_array( $selection ) ) {

        $label = $selection['label'];
        $value = $selection['value'];

    } else {

        $label = strtolower( $selection );
        $value = strtolower( $selection );

    }
    ?>

    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>" <?php selected( $atts['value'], $value ); ?>>
        <?php esc_html_e( $label, $this->plugin_name ); ?>
    </option>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Does anybody have any ideas at all? It's probably something obvious with a simple solution, and I'll surely kick myself. But please. HELP. ME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I'm kicking myself. The select fields weren't saving because for some bizarre reason, at some point when I was working on this, their names weren't formatted correctly, i.e. `background` instead of `plugin-name[background]`. Such a simple solution to an obvious error!